# Ultimate Member Wordpress plugin: code (att) lets one user select other user, a CPT or certain posts to display at their profile. Not quite working

Tags: wordpress, roles, profile, ultimate-member

using latest version of WP / plugins, - I'm trying to allow one Ultimate Member user to select other users of a certain role, to display them on their UM profile page.

I found a piece of code written in a plugin which seems to be mainly working - but just not quite perfectly! Can you see anything glaring out as an issue in this code? It's a full plugin, just one file, code attached below.

This code sets up an extra tab called ‘field relationships’ in the UM settings. You can then add a field in the Ultimate Member profile form (either dropdown or multi select), and put the word ‘relationship’ in the first row of the options.

Then you take the meta key you chose from that field you created, and specify in the field relationships tab in UM settings which relationship you want to display from a choice of 3. You can allow the role which the form with your new profile field applies to display 1) Users from a certain role using the user role's UM slug , or 2) A certain taxonomy of post or 3) Certain post ids.

It's a super simple plugin, once you have chosen and added the info in the profile form and the UM settings tab, the field you set up appears as an option for any role/s you attributed that UM profile form to, in ‘edit profile’, with a search box or dropdown (whichever you chose) for the user to select what they want to display.

In my case I’m trying to display users of a certain role, so that for instance if one user role was Musical Theatre Play, they could select every user with the type Actor who was performing in the play and they would display on the Musical Theatre Play's profile.

I’ve checked and double checked it’s set up right, and it does work to pull up the users I want, exactly as it should …..but frustratingly just not ALL users of that role appear as choices in that search form, only two of them!

Users on my site can have multiple roles but I’ve checked that the users that don’t display all share the correct user role as the primary role, and they definitely do.

I’ve already checked that there’s nothing in the Ultimate Member Profile Forms or User Roles limiting visibility of a certain role etc, there isn’t.

The code below also offers the chance to select the user option as your type and then -not- select a specific role, and this means -all- users will turn up in the search, to give the user the chance to pick from -any- of the other users without it being role specific. This option works fine if that helps, and all users appear, but that isn’t what I need, I just need a comma separated list of certain roles as it's supposed to do.

I noticed logging into the database that the users showing up seem to have the role listed under wp_capabilities in the user meta where those that don’t show don’t seem to have that, but instead have my-custom-db-name_capabilities.

Also, I’ve changed the sign up process, a user now registers as a subscriber to enter via the standard Ultimate Member reg form, then is redirected to a page after reg where they are asked to activate a certain account type, which then serves to 'upgrade' that user via a membership from a plugin called paidmemberships pro https://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/. Their chosen upgrade then attributes a membership and attaches the fitting Ultimate Member roles to their login via a plugin. Could this be an issue? I was originally just using S2 Member to have a user subscribe via a button and attributing caps to the S2 level. https://wordpress.org/plugins/s2member/.

Now - when I check my roles in admin, all seems to work exactly as it should, and the rest of the UM outcomes related to these roles work too, for example the correct profile forms display for each role, the correct redirects happen for the role type, they show up fine in the directories they should etc....

The only problem I have is this code, not all users with the role I set show up in the search form in the ‘edit profile’ screen after activating this code.

Thanks in advance for any ideas about this puzzle!

```
<?php
 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

define( 'PP_FIELDS_REQUIRES', '1.3.28' );

class PP_Fields {
    public $notice_messge = '';
    public $plugin_inactive = false;

    function __construct() {
        $this->plugin_inactive = false;

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'plugin_check' ), 10 );
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'add_notice' ), 20 );
        add_filter( 'um_settings_structure', array( $this, 'add_field_relationships_tab' ), 200, 60 );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ), 100 );
    }

    function plugin_check() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'UM' ) ) {
            $this->notice_messge   = __( 'The <strong>UM Relational Fields</strong> extension requires the Ultimate Member plugin to be activated to work properly. You can download it <a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member">here</a>', 'pp-contact' );
            $this->plugin_inactive = true;
        } else if ( ! version_compare( ultimatemember_version, PP_FIELDS_REQUIRES, '>=' ) ) {
            $this->notice_messge   = __( 'The <strong>UM Relational Fields</strong> extension requires a <a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member">newer version</a> of Ultimate Member to work properly.', 'pp-contact' );
            $this->plugin_inactive = true;
        }
    }

    function add_notice() {
        if ( ! is_admin() || empty( $this->notice_messge ) ) {
            return;
        }

        echo '<div class="error"><p>' . $this->notice_messge . '</p></div>';
    }

    function add_field_relationships_tab( $sections ) {
        ob_start();
        ?>

        <h2>Enter a relationship in the following format</h2>
        <pre>meta_key|type|slug|link</pre>
        <h4>meta_key</h4>
        <p>This is the meta key of the field generated in the UM Form Builder.<br>
            <strong>Important:</strong> The field type should be either <code>dropdown</code> or
            <code>multiselect</code>, and "relationship" should be added in the first line of the options field of the
            Form Builder.</p>
        <h4>type</h4>
        <p>This is type of item you are relating to - either <code>user</code>, <code>tax</code> or <code>post</code>.
        </p>
        <h4>slug</h4>
        <p>If your <code>type</code> is <code>user</code>, this value is the user role slug that will filter the options
            in the select area. Multiple user roles should be defined as a comma-seperated list eg.
            <code>admin,member</code>. Leave empty to add all user roles.<br>
            If your <code>type</code> is <code>tax</code>, this value is the taxonomy slug that will filter the options
            in the select area. A single taxonomy slug must be entered.<br>
            If your <code>type</code> is <code>post</code>, this value is the comma seperated list of post types slugs
            that filter the options in the select area.</p>
        <h4>link</h4>
        <p>Set this value to <code>true</code> if you want to hyperlink the users or posts in display mode on the
            profile, or <code>false</code> to disable hyperlinks. If your type is <code>user</code>, you can also use
            <code>avatar</code> here to display an avatar.</p>
        <h4>Examples</h4>
        <p><code>my_coach|user|coach|true</code></p>
        <p><code>fav_meal|post|recipes|true</code></p>
        <p><code>recommended_content|post|post,page|true</code></p>
        <p><code>friends|user||false</code></p>
        <p><code>category|tax|category|true</code></p>
        <h4>Questions?</h4>
        <p>Shoot us an email: <strong>info@plusplugins.com</strong></p>

        <?php
        $desc = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $fields = array(
            array(
                'id'       => 'field_relationships',
                'type'     => 'multi_text',
                'default'  => array(),
                'add_text' => __( 'Add New Relationship', 'ultimatemember' ),
                'label'    => 'Field Relationships',
            ),
            array(
                'id'       => 'field_instructions',
                'type'     => 'custom',
                'add_text' => __( 'Field Instructions', 'ultimatemember' ),
                'label'    => 'Field Instructions',
                'description'=> $desc,
            )
        );

        $sections['sections'] = array(

            'icon'       => 'um-faicon-exchange',
            'title'      => __( 'Field Relationships', 'pp-fields' ),
            'fields'     => $fields,
            'subsection' => false,

        );

        return $sections;
    }

    function init() {
        if ( $this->plugin_inactive ) {
            return;
        }

        global $ultimatemember;

        $relationships = um_get_option( 'field_relationships' );

        if ( empty( $relationships ) ) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ( $relationships as $relationship ) {
            $args = array_map( 'trim', explode( "|", trim( $relationship ) ) );

            $key  = isset( $args[0] ) ? $args[0] : '';
            $type = isset( $args[1] ) ? $args[1] : '';
            $slug = isset( $args[2] ) ? $args[2] : '';
            $link = isset( $args[3] ) ? $args[3] : '';

            if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
                add_action( 'um_before_form', function ( $args ) use ( $type, $key, $slug, $link ) {
                    $this->profile_form( $type, $key, $slug, $link );
                }, 10, 1 );

                $this->search_form( $type, $key, $slug, $link );
                $this->filtered_value( $type, $key, $slug, $link );
            }
        }
    }

    function items( $type, $slug ) {
        $items = array();

        if ( $type == 'user' ) {
            $args = array();

            if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
                $roles = explode( ",", $slug );

                $args['meta_key']     = 'role';
                $args['meta_value']   = $roles;
                $args['meta_compare'] = 'IN';
            }

            $items = get_users( $args );
        }

        if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
            $items = get_terms( array( $slug ), array( 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
        }

        if ( $type == 'post' ) {
            $post_types = array();

            if ( empty( $slug ) ) {
                $post_types[] = 'post';
            } else {
                $post_types = explode( ",", $slug );
            }

            $items = get_posts( array( "post_type" => $post_types, 'posts_per_page' => 999 ) );
        }

        return $items;
    }

    function options( $items, $type ) {
        $options = array();

        if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                $options[ $item->term_id ] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-tax-option-field', $item->name, $item );
            }
        }

        if ( $type == 'user' ) {
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                $options[ $item->ID ] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-user-option-field', $item->display_name, $item );
            }
        }

        if ( $type == 'post' ) {
            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                $options[ $item->ID ] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-post-option-field', $item->post_title, $item );
            }
        }

        asort( $options );

        return $options;
    }

    function search_form( $type, $key, $slug, $link ) {
        add_filter( "um_search_field_{$key}", function ( $attrs ) use ( $type, $key, $slug ) {
            $items   = $this->items( $type, $slug );
            $options = $this->options( $items, $type );

            $attrs['options'] = $options;
            $attrs['custom']  = true;

            return $attrs;
        }, 100, 1 );
    }

    function profile_form( $type, $key, $slug, $link ) {
        $profile_id = um_profile_id();

        add_filter( "um_{$key}_form_edit_field", function ( $output, $mode ) use ( $type, $key, $slug, $profile_id ) {
            $ids     = get_user_meta( $profile_id, $key, true );
            $replace = '<option value=""></option>';
            $items   = $this->items( $type, $slug );
            $options = $this->options( $items, $type );

            foreach ( $options as $k => $v ) {
                $selected = '';

                if ( is_array( $ids ) ) {
                    if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                        if ( in_array( $k, $ids ) ) {
                            $selected = 'selected';
                        }
                    } elseif ( in_array( $k, $ids ) ) {
                        $selected = 'selected';
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                        if ( $k == $ids ) {
                            $selected = 'selected';
                        }
                    } elseif ( $k == $ids ) {
                        $selected = 'selected';
                    }
                }

                $replace .= '<option value="' . $k . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $v . '</option>';
            }

            $output = preg_replace( '%<option .*</option>%', $replace, $output );

            return $output;
        }, 10, 2 );

        add_filter( "um_{$key}_form_show_field", function ( $output, $mode ) use ( $type, $key, $slug, $link, $profile_id ) {
            $ids = get_user_meta( $profile_id, $key, true );

            if ( ! is_array( $ids ) ) {
                $ids = array( $ids );
            }

            $replace = '<div class="um-field-value">';
            $items   = array();

            if ( $type == 'user' ) {
                $items = get_users( array( 'include' => $ids ) );
            }

            if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                $items = get_terms( array( $slug ), array( 'include' => $ids, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
            }

            if ( $type == 'post' ) {
                $post_types = explode( ",", $slug );
                $items      = get_posts( array(
                    'include'        => $ids,
                    'post_type'      => $post_types,
                    'posts_per_page' => 999
                ) );
            }

            $replace = '<div class="um-field-value">';

            $names = array();

            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                if ( $type == 'user' ) {
                    um_fetch_user( $item->ID );

                    $result = $item->display_name;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . um_user_profile_url() . '">' . $item->display_name . '</a>';
                    } elseif ( $link == 'avatar' ) {
                        $result = '<a style="display:inline-block" href="' . um_user_profile_url() . '" class="um-tip-s" title="' . um_user( 'display_name' ) . '">' . get_avatar( $item->ID, 140 ) . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-user-display-field', $result, $item );
                }

                if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                    $result = $item->name;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $item ) . '">' . $item->name . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-tax-value-field', $result, $item );
                }

                if ( $type == 'post' ) {
                    $result = $item->post_title;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item ) . '">' . $item->post_title . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-post-value-field', $result, $item );
                }
            }

            // return to profile user data
            um_fetch_user( $profile_id );

            if ( $link == "avatar" ) {
                $replace .= implode( " ", $names );
            } else {
                $replace .= implode( ", ", $names );
            }

            $replace .= '</div>';

            $find = '%<div class="um-field-value">([0-9,\s]+)*</div>%';

            $output = preg_replace( $find, $replace, $output );

            return $output;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Show relation on Profile Card in Members Directory
     *
     * @param $type
     * @param $key
     * @param $slug
     * @param $link
     */
    function filtered_value( $type, $key, $slug, $link ) {

        add_filter( "um_profile_field_filter_hook__{$key}", function ( $value, $data ) use ( $type, $key, $slug, $link ) {

            $profile_id = um_user( 'ID' );

            $ids = get_user_meta( $profile_id, $key, true );

            if ( ! is_array( $ids ) ) {
                $ids = array( $ids );
            }

            $items = array();

            if ( $type == 'user' ) {
                $items = get_users( array( 'include' => $ids ) );
            }

            if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                $items = get_terms( array( $slug ), array( 'include' => $ids, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
            }

            if ( $type == 'post' ) {
                $post_types = explode( ",", $slug );
                $items      = get_posts( array(
                    'include'        => $ids,
                    'post_type'      => $post_types,
                    'posts_per_page' => 999
                ) );
            }

            $modified_value = '<div class="um-field-value">';

            $names = array();

            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                if ( $type == 'user' ) {
                    um_fetch_user( $item->ID );

                    $result = $item->display_name;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . um_user_profile_url() . '">' . $item->display_name . '</a>';
                    } elseif ( $link == 'avatar' ) {
                        $result = '<a style="display:inline-block" href="' . um_user_profile_url() . '" class="um-tip-s" title="' . um_user( 'display_name' ) . '">' . get_avatar( $item->ID, 140 ) . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-user-display-field', $result, $item );
                }

                if ( $type == 'tax' ) {
                    $result = $item->name;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $item ) . '">' . $item->name . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-tax-value-field', $result, $item );
                }

                if ( $type == 'post' ) {
                    $result = $item->post_title;

                    if ( $link == 'true' ) {
                        $result = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $item ) . '">' . $item->post_title . '</a>';
                    }

                    $names[] = apply_filters( 'pp-fields-post-value-field', $result, $item );
                }
            }

            // return to profile user data
            um_fetch_user( $profile_id );

            if ( $link == "avatar" ) {
                $modified_value .= implode( " ", $names );
            } else {
                $modified_value .= implode( ", ", $names );
            }

            $modified_value .= '</div>';

            return $modified_value;

        }, 10, 2 );
    }
}

new PP_Fields();
```